# Change a specified line in QMenu

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a simple script like I added above. My Problem is to change a specified line in the popup menu without adding all again and again because it's too slow and refreshes all the popup lines which causes flashing.

My code is:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

class MyLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self,action, line_number = 0, sel_line = -1):
        super(MyLabel,self).__init__()
        self.action = action
        self.SelectedStyle   = "QLabel { color: rgb( 22, 22, 250 ); font-weight:normal ; font-size: 11px; background-color: rgb(1, 1, 238, 255); border: 1px solid rgba(88, 88, 88, 10); }" 
        # self.NormalStyle     = "QLabel { color: %s; font-weight:bold ; font-size: %dpx; background-color: rgba(125, 125, 115, 255); border: 3px solid %s; } " % ( txtcol,fontsize,border )
        self.NormalStyle     = "QLabel { color: rgb( 22, 22, 22 ); font-weight:normal ; font-size: 11px; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238, 255); border: 1px solid rgba(88, 88, 88, 10); }" 

        if line_number == sel_line:# and self.parent().in_focus == False:
            self.NormalStyle = self.SelectedStyle
            self.setStyleSheet( self.NormalStyle)

    # colorize the selected line 
    def enterEvent( self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet( self.SelectedStyle)

    # set back the not selection line to default color
    def leaveEvent( self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet( self.NormalStyle)

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        mpos = QtGui.QCursor
        x = mpos.pos().x()
        y = mpos.pos().y()
        self.qmenu = popQMenu( )

        self.qmenu.show()
        self.qmenu.setGeometry( x-11, y-11, 101, 101)
        # self.show()
        self.qmenu.exec_()



        qMenu.setGeometry( x-10, y-10, 0, 0)
        qMenu.show()
        qMenu.exec_()

        # self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')    
        # self.show()

class popQMenu( QtGui.QMenu):
    def __init__( self):

        super( popQMenu, self).__init__()
        self.sel_line_pos = 2
        self.ShowPopup()

    def ShowPopup(self):
        self.clear()
        for i in range( 52):
            wAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self)
            ql = MyLabel(wAction, i, self.sel_line_pos )
            ql.setText("<u>Hello</u> <i>Qt!</i>")
            wAction.setData( '1')
            wAction.setDefaultWidget(ql)
            self.addAction(wAction)

    def MenuSelected( self):
        action = self.sender()
        print action.data()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print 'right mouse pressed'
            pass
    # check for the typed string for filtering it
    def keyPressEvent( self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            print self.sel_line_pos
            if self.sel_line_pos >= 1:
                self.sel_line_pos -= 1

        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            print self.sel_line_pos
            if self.sel_line_pos < 22:
                self.sel_line_pos += 1
        self.ShowPopup()



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance!
G

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you want?  This code seems to basically work, though there are three styles involved: initial, after enter, and after leave.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to include an MVCE.  The code you have posted does not demonstrate your issue and contains other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to do, but there are various problems in your code.  For example, you are using `background-color` instead of `background`.

Another problem is that you don't set the `MyLabel` to `NormalStyle` when it is first created (in the `__init__` method).

With those two changes, the mouse cursor part seems to mostly work for me.  On the other hand, you now seem to be having trouble with the cursor key part.  Here is a cut down example of how you can get that to work:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

SelectedStyle   = "QLabel { color: rgb( 22, 22, 250 ); font-weight:normal ; font-size: 11px; background-color: rgb(1, 1, 238, 255); border: 1px solid rgba(88, 88, 88, 10); }" 
NormalStyle     = "QLabel { color: rgb( 22, 22, 22 ); font-weight:normal ; font-size: 11px; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238, 255); border: 1px solid rgba(88, 88, 88, 10); }" 

class MyLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self,action, line_number = 0, sel_line = -1):
        super(MyLabel,self).__init__()
        self.action = action

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        mpos = QtGui.QCursor
        x = mpos.pos().x()
        y = mpos.pos().y()
        self.qmenu = popQMenu( )
        self.qmenu.show()
        self.qmenu.setGeometry( x-11, y-11, 101, 101)
        self.qmenu.exec_()

class popQMenu( QtGui.QMenu):
    def __init__( self):
        super( popQMenu, self).__init__()
        self.sel_line_pos = 2
        self.widgets = []
        for i in range( 22):
            wAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self)
            ql = MyLabel(wAction, i, self.sel_line_pos )
            ql.setStyleSheet( NormalStyle)
            ql.setText("<u>Hello</u> <i>Qt!</i>")
            self.widgets.append(ql)
            wAction.setDefaultWidget(ql)
            self.addAction(wAction)
        self.widgets[self.sel_line_pos].setStyleSheet( SelectedStyle)

    def keyPressEvent( self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            if self.sel_line_pos >= 1:
                self.widgets[self.sel_line_pos].setStyleSheet( NormalStyle)
                self.sel_line_pos -= 1
                self.widgets[self.sel_line_pos].setStyleSheet( SelectedStyle)

        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            if self.sel_line_pos < 22:
                self.widgets[self.sel_line_pos].setStyleSheet( NormalStyle)
                self.sel_line_pos += 1
                self.widgets[self.sel_line_pos].setStyleSheet( SelectedStyle)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'll leave it to you to get them to work together - it should be easy.

Comment: Thanks and sorry maybe I was not very clear. I would like to change only one line color. For example I use the keyboard arrow keys to move the selection ( darked blue popup line  ). So when In my script use self.clear() and add all the lines again the window seems flashing.. Here is my whole script. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zp3mgk78i9izi3q/hipBrowser.py?dl=0

Comment: OK I don't know how to change a single menu line.  Not sure if it is possible.  I think you should build an MVCE and replace the code in your question with that.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the code. I hope it helps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you call showPopup in the keyPressEvent?  Why not just change the style on the selected and deselected labels?

Comment: Sorry , It is not clear to me. If I have the selected line number by the arrow keys after I need the refresh of the popup somehow.. That's why I call it,

Comment: Why?  You don't refresh it in the leaveEvent.

Comment: You are right but the keypress event is at class popQmenu not at MyLabel class. Maybe I am a bit new in programing PySide.. Can you help ? THanks

Comment: I have added some more code.  But the point of stack overflow it to create questions and answers of general utility, not to debug your program.  You need to make questions focused on a specific problem.  If you still can't make progress you need to start a new question based on what you specifically don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your code too. You helped. May I ask ( here this topic  :) ) where or what pages you learned pyside from ?